# Trying to return sum of array, method call error

Tags: java, for-loop, recursion, methods

I am trying to return the sum of my array, however I instead of summing the array using recursion, the array sum just comes back as 0. I'm at that point where I think I may be overlooking something. An extra set of eyes would help out.

```
public class JavaSandbox {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static int sumDanceScore(int danceScore[], int first, int last)
{


  if (first > last) 
    {
      return 0;
    }
 else
    {
     int total = sumDanceScore(danceScore,first+1,last) + danceScore[first];
     return total;
    }
}
  public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter number of contestants : ");

   int numContest = kbd.nextInt();
   int danceScore[] = new int[numContest + 1];
   int first = 0;
   int last = danceScore.length - 1;

   System.out.println("Enter dance scores: ");

  int numContestIndex;
  for (numContestIndex = 1; numContestIndex <= numContest; numContestIndex++) {
  danceScore[numContestIndex] = kbd.nextInt();
}

     int danceScoreTotal = sumDanceScore(danceScore, first, last);
     System.out.println("SUM DANCE SORE METHOD: "+danceScoreTotal);
     for(int danceScoreIndex = 1; danceScoreIndex <= danceScore.length-1; danceScoreIndex++)
  {
     int danceScoreShare = danceScore[danceScoreIndex] /  danceScoreTotal;
    System.out.println("DANCE SCORE SHARE "+danceScoreShare);
  }

}

}
```

Comment: To help SO users to review your code, please format the code

Comment: Sorry, Let me try and fix it been a long day.

Comment: You are requesting input after calculating the sum

Answer (score 4):

In your code you invoke your function `sumDanceScore` before filling in the array. Thus, you pass an array filled with zeroes (as default values) to the function.

Answer (score 0):

How to fix:

- index `first` initialize to zero.
- function `sumDanceScore` after filling in the array

How does recursion work on your `sumDanceScore`?

First, `sumDanceScore` is called for `first == 0` and `last == danceScore.length - 1` array. Then, the `sumDanceScore` leaves the initial element (in the `first` position) of the range and call next `sumDanceScore` with shifted position by one. This `first == 1` and this variable is different from when calling `sumDanceScore` first time. Displace each time `first`, until `first` matches the `last`.

This is correct `main` body:

```
Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter number of contestants : ");

int numContest = kbd.nextInt();
int danceScore[] = new int[numContest + 1];
int first = 0;
int last = danceScore.length - 1;

System.out.println("Enter dance scores: ");

int numContestIndex;
for (numContestIndex = 1; numContestIndex <= numContest; numContestIndex++) {
    danceScore[numContestIndex] = kbd.nextInt();
}

int danceScoreTotal = sumDanceScore(danceScore, first, last);

System.out.println("SUM DANCE SORE METHOD: " + danceScoreTotal);
```

Comment: Anatoly Would you happen to be able to tell  me why when I try to divide my danceScore array index by the sumDanceScore I have 0's in place of all my danceScore array slots. I have edited the code.

Comment: @davidwillams edit answer with an explanation of how recursion is worked.